# MYSQL variable and escape string issue

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get this to work but I have no idea what's wrong with it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $datatable ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $start_from,
$results_per_page WHERE STATE='$category'" ;
```

The following one works and just shows the entire table. But I'm running into issues when I try to use `WHERE STATE=Variable`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$datatable." ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_page ;
```

Comment: Use [Parameterized Queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write "ORDER BY" after the "WHERE" part.
In your case it should be something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $datatable WHERE STATE='$category' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $start_from, $results_per_page" ;
```